# erro matlab: Too many elements

Tags: matlab

Como ler uma arquivo .txt que possua muitos elementos? Para poucos elementos o comando dlmread funciona, mas para matrizes de grande ordem não.

Comment: Qual é a dimensão da matriz?

Comment: O utilizador já colocou a pergunta previamente...